Los datos me aoarecen amontonadas o no aparecen en windows forms C#
Los datos me aparecen todos encimados, o solo se agrupan en un solo dato y no se porque, he intentado detallar cada aspecto del chart y no cambia la forma en que se presentan los datos este es mi  codigo
 private void GraficaPartos()
 {
     DataTable consulta = con.ReporteDestetes(timeInicio.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), timeFinal.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
     foreach (DataRow row in consulta.Rows)
     {
         string numeroArete = row["NumeroArete"].ToString();
         double destetes = row["Destetados"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(row["Destetados"]) : 0;

         chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(numeroArete, destetes);
     }

     LLenarGridDestetes(consulta);
 }

No Tengo mucha experiencia pero he intentado cambiar de grafico y el único grafico que resulta es el de pastel pero no es el formato que me solicitan
Y ya vi muchos tutoriales pero no se porque los datos aparecen encimados de esta forma, espero puedan ayudarme, la tabla consultas solo es una consulta en sql que me arroja justo la tabla que viene aun lado del grafico, no debería haber mas problema

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Sin saber que tipo de grafico intentas, es dificil ayudarte.. ahi estas agregando todos los puntos a la misma serie.. estas seguro querias hacer eso???
